# Is the mass function of dark matter halos fundamental or an approximation based on experimental data?

Tags: galaxy, dark-matter

Can the [halo mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_mass_function) be derived from existing physics or is it just a best fit of some data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the statistics of the cosmological initial conditions (e.g. the [matter power spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_power_spectrum)), the halo mass function can be predicted from first principles using so-called [excursion set theory](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991ApJ...379..440B) (the simplest form of which is [Press-Schechter theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press%E2%80%93Schechter_formalism)). Consider the cosmological initial conditions -- that is, the density field at a time when fractional variations in the density of the universe are tiny. The basic idea of excursion set theory is to say that if the average density of a region (typically a sphere) in the initial conditions exceeds a set threshold, then that region is part of a halo at the present time (or some other chosen time).

The procedure is to start at some arbitrarily large scale, such that nothing of that scale exceeds the density threshold. For example, if you are considering the whole universe, it has zero excess density, with respect to the cosmological average. Then you can consider successively smaller regions in the initial conditions. Eventually, you might find that the region you are considering exceeds the density threshold. If that happens, you've identified a portion of the initial field that becomes a halo at the later time. The mass of that initial region is the mass of the halo.

Mathematically this can be modeled as a random walk. The density contrast, relative to the mean, is essentially zero for a region of arbitrarily large mass. As you decrease the size of the region, the density could randomly go up or down. The goal is to find the statistical distribution of masses at which your regions first cross the density threshold. This leads directly to the halo mass function.

Comment: Doesn't this all assume that before inflation vacuum fluctuations produced dark matter with a statistical probability the same as for quarks leptons etc. How is it known that the density contrast field is Gaussian at large scales? I think I have understood the links in your post Let me know if I haven't.

Comment: @DaveTheWave Those two assumptions -- that initial fluctuations are gaussian and adiabatic -- are not required by excursion set theory in principle, although they are commonly made when applying it. They are very well tested anyway; see for example [Constraints on primordial non-Gaussianity](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2020/09/aa35891-19/aa35891-19.html) and [Baryons still trace dark matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03461).